# maven artifact regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I am in the process of creating a bom (http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) for my project. My Project has a lot of dependencies... So I created a little ruby script that would generate the xml for me. But I fall short when it comes to the regex, that determins the artifactId. Assume I have the following 3 Paths:

- /Users/buddy/Downloads/jboss-esb/client/hibernate-commons-annotations.jar
- /Users/buddy/Downloads/jboss-esb/client/ejb3-persistence.jar
- /Users/buddy/Downloads/jboss-esb/server/default/deploy/spring.esb/spring-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar

And I am trying to find a regex, that only returns me

- hibernate-commons-annotations
- ejb3-persistence
- spring-core

The before mentioned paths are in the variable filename and I have this regex to determine the version and the artifactId (obviously I have some default version in case there is no version in the filename)

```
@version = version
if temp_version = filename[/-([\d+{1,3}\.A-Z]+).jar/,1]
  @version = temp_version
end
@artifactId = filename[/.*\/([\w\d]+\-?[^\d^\-]*)\-?[\d+\.A-Z]*.jar/,1]
```

but it will not work in all cases.

Any help to make the regex work in all cases, and a simplified version of the regex is highly appreciated.

Comment: Btw what is wrong with your version regex?

Comment: the version regex is fine. I just added it for the sake of completeness, so no maven god tries to get both the artifactId and the Version with the same regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex works

```
.+\/(.+?)(-\d|.jar)
```

tested [here](http://rubular.com/r/2C5lBPxQu2), look in the groups (the first, accessible with `$1`) for the strings you are looking for.

EDIT:

I assume that any version is part of the filename and starts with a minus and a digit, thus the file string will terminate if the regex finds `-3` `-0` and so on.

Comment: works like a charm, and the regex, so simple ;) Sometimes one just thinks to strict :-)